# Nginx 403 forbidden with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to install wordpress on CentOS with nginx and php-fpm and MySQL.

After I install nginx and wordpress. Access any path just get 403 forbidden error.

This is nginx config

```
user  nginx nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;
        root /home/wordpress;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

and fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

My root path is `/home/wordpress`.

And the `namei -om /home/wordpress` is:

```
f: /home/wordpress/
 dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
 drwxr-xr-x root  root  home
 drwxrwxrwx nginx nginx wordpress
```

I found if change the `location /` add `index` config as

```
    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

I can access example.com and get the correct content.
Anything else is also 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Check the nginx error logs. You'll find something like:

```
 *472430 directory index of "/home/wordpress" is forbidden
```

You should move `index` declaration to server block:

```
server {
   root /home/wordpress;
   index index.php;
}
```

Moreover make sure to set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to `0`. e.g. by executing

```
sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/" php.ini
```

You can find your `ini` files using `php --ini`.

Restart `php-fpm` and your site should load normally.